# Graph curve is not correct in relation to the highest point reported

Tags: c#, uwp, livecharts

As we can see in the Basic Line Chart example, we observe that the curve made by the graph is not corresponding to the highest point reported.

For example, `Y = 6` and `X = Feb` (Blue Line), we can see that the graph curve shows a slightly higher point that was not reported.

When trying to use the graph, it was noticed this error that is shown in the figure.
The point (Y = 6 X = FEB) represented by a blue circle, should be at the center of the graph curve.

We are use UWP

```
new LineSeries { Title = "Series 1", Values = new ChartValues<double> { 4, 6, 5, 2 ,4 }
```

**On the graph it seems that there is a value greater than 6.**

The demo is wrong. [enter link description here](http://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Basic%20Line%20Chart)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @Ddson, can you please add more details in your question, it's hard to understand what is the problem and what help you need.

Comment: @NirmalMangal When trying to use the graph, it was noticed this error that is shown in the figure.
The point (Y = 6 X = FEB) represented by a blue circle, should be at the center of the graph curve.

Comment: Does the blue line data array contains Y that more than 6? and please share your code and which chart lib you have used.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT -> The demo is wrong. https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Basic%20Line%20Chart

Comment: new LineSeries
                {
                    Title = "Series 1",
                    Values = new ChartValues<double> { 4, 6, 5, 2 ,4 }
                },
On the graph it seems that there is a value greater than 6.